# Which Nvidia driver is needed for a GT 610 graphics card?

Tags: nvidia, system-settings, ubuntu-drivers

I have ubuntu 15.04 and I need to get a graphics driver I tried the most recent, but it made my system settings not open. What driver would you recommend? I am doing a reinstall by the way.

Comment: Did you install from the Additional Drivers program or from the website itself?

Comment: Additional drivers. Is that a problem?

Comment: If so I need to know where to look for an linux driver from nvidia somewhere on their site.

Comment: No, getting it from the program is the best way to go. If you got the newest version from there, get maybe 304 or 314. Try the other versions. In my experience, there's no definitive way to tell which driver is best, as even the same NVIDIA card can work differently in different situations. NVIDIA is unstable to begin with on Ubuntu, so it's usually trial and error until you find the driver that works for you. (I sound like one of those TV ads =) )

Comment: I will try a different driver and will repeat unless I get a worse issue

Comment: Also would be good for one of these drivers to actually work

Comment: It would. I don't really know why NVIDIA is so bad on Ubuntu, but it is disappointing.

Comment: Yeah you're telling me just recently  figured out what was wrong

Comment: Still a wrong driver by the way

Comment: Keep trying them.

Comment: All but neuveau have the same result...

Comment: I'm going to try a legacy driver from the software center

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers supporting GT 610 from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

Before you install new drivers uninstall every NVIDIA related software you have installed before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Then install the latest current stable NVIDIA drivers from the long-lived branch by executing :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 
sudo reboot
```

In case you are using a notebook with a hybrid graphics solution install Optimus support as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

To switch between intel and nvidia graphics - open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles**.

Comment: @nerd7473 first - delete all your old comments because the system asked me to avoid extended discussion - I already deleted mine - so then uninstall NVIDIA and reinstall Unity : sudo apt-get purge nvidia* | sudo apt-get update | sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop | sudo apt-get install unity | sudo reboot - post back please ! :)

Comment: I'm not at home I will when I get there