# Can Ubuntu utilize a i7(4 core)?

Tags: performance

My pc has 8 Gb ram with a intel i7(4 core - logical 8) processor and NVIDIA GeForce GT 610 (2GB) graphics card.

One of my friend told me that Ubuntu or any linux distribution can not utilize this resources :/

Kinda sad, will any one explain this a little?

Thanks, have a great day there :)

Comment: Your friend is wrong, no explanation needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your friend is wrong - Ubuntu can utilize all your hardware perfectly well.

If you want to play games, or do other video intensive tasks, you *may*  want to install Nvidia's driver's for your graphics card. See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/684340/which-nvidia-driver-is-needed-for-a-gt-610-graphics-card) for details. (However, the open source drivers which ship with Ubuntu will probably be fine - meaning that Ubuntu will work well right away, out of the box, with no further set-up.)

Comment: I'd agrue you should always install the proprietary drivers...

Comment: ..And I'd argue that you shouldn't, unless you need them :-)

Comment: I would argue that if you have the card then you need the drivers, the close used source ones are much better than nouveau but the gap is closing

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: @rakibtg The proprietary drivers (may) have better performance, is this what you mean ?