# Screen glitches during login

Tags: 16.04, login-screen, multiple-monitors

I decided to start running dual monitors on my computer. A few days after that whenever I log in to my computer after I enter my password but before the desktop screen loads up there is a graphical glitch at the bottom of my right monitor. It turns white and most of the time shows what looks kind of like static as shown here: [image: right monitor] But after that the computer works normally. So my question is how can I get it to where it does not do this?

Comment: Now that you have over 10 reputation, please feel free to include a screenshot :) What graphics card do you have?

Comment: I have an nvidia GT 610

Comment: It looks like because you have two monitors of different size, the driver is not properly initializing the resolution until after you login, for whatever reason. Perhaps because it needs to read it from your a user config file? Idk. Have you tried the proprietary Nvidia drivers? As a general rule of thumb, don't use proprietary drivers unless you really need to. That said, please see this question: 

http://askubuntu.com/questions/684340/which-nvidia-driver-is-needed-for-a-gt-610-graphics-card

and see if using another driver solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be what your looking for, but it would work to clear up your static issue . . . and give you the option for a different wallpaper on each monitor.  A little wallpaper utility named "nitrogen".  You can use apt-get install to grab it or you can find it in the software manager.  This is a workaround though not a fix, but it is really easy to use.  Then just set it up in your autrun settings like "Name: Nitrogen, Command: **nitrogen --restore**, Comment: whatever you want".  To add your image folder click on preferences and go from there, pretty self explanatory.